# Throw error 'Only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed' when using babel?

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6, frontend, babeljs

I am developing a plugin using ES6, but after importing the plugin in my project, I get 'Only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed' error.
Does that mean I can't use babel-polyfill then developing plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem. In my case solution was a babel-polyfill inclusion check.

```
if (!window._babelPolyfill) {
require('babel-polyfill')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally only overall applications should be loading global plugins. If you're writing a library like a Babel plugin, you should either assume the user of your library will load it for you, or you should use [`transform-runtime`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-runtime/).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was caused by an attempt of including `babel.polyfill.min.js` when it was already included.